# Is it possible to create a gem of a rails app and not just ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a ruby gem which is nothing but a bunch of shared models. Is it possible to convert this gem into a standalone rails app but still be included in other rails app as a dependency in gemfile.

Comment: You mean _shared modules_ ?